# toString the data Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to do some regex operation operation on a column. In order to do that I stated with the basic lowercase operation as below:

```
df.select('name').map(lambda x: x.lower())
```

Here df is a DataFrame, and the operation is throwing an exception when I call collect() operation.

```
Ques 1: After map(or reduce) operation, every DataFrame converts to a Pipelined RDD. Am I right?
```

If so, why this command throwing exception while collecting the Pipelined RDD.

Am I missing anything?

Exception is too big to read:

```
    17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at <stdin>:1
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 55 (collect at <stdin>:1) with 4 output partitions
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 63 (collect at <stdin>:1)
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 63 (PythonRDD[195] at collect at <stdin>:1), which has no missing parents
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_61 stored as values in memory (estimated size 11.7 KB, free 11.7 KB)
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_61_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 6.7 KB, free 18.3 KB)
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_61_piece0 in memory on localhost:54574 (size: 6.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 61 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 4 missing tasks from ResultStage 63 (PythonRDD[195] at collect at <stdin>:1)
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 63.0 with 4 tasks
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 63.0 (TID 744, localhost, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2097 bytes)
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 63.0 (TID 745, localhost, partition 1,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2131 bytes)
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 63.0 (TID 746, localhost, partition 2,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2132 bytes)
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 63.0 (TID 747, localhost, partition 3,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2131 bytes)
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 63.0 (TID 744)
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 63.0 (TID 745)
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 63.0 (TID 746)
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO Executor: Running task 3.0 in stage 63.0 (TID 747)
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 22, boot = 14, init = 7, finish = 1
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 11, boot = 7, init = 3, finish = 1
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 8, boot = 4, init = 3, finish = 1
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 56, boot = 30, init = 26, finish = 0
17/07/07 13:51:41 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 63.0 (TID 746)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1272, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: lower

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/07/07 13:51:41 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 63.0 (TID 747)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1272, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: lower

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/07/07 13:51:41 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 63.0 (TID 744)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1272, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: lower

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/07/07 13:51:41 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 63.0 (TID 745)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1272, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: lower

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/07/07 13:51:41 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 63.0 (TID 745, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1272, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: lower

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/07/07 13:51:41 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 63.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 63.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 63.0 (TID 744) on executor localhost: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException (Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1272, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: lower
) [duplicate 1]
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 63.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 63.0 (TID 747) on executor localhost: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException (Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1272, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: lower
) [duplicate 2]
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 63.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 63.0 (TID 746) on executor localhost: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException (Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1272, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: lower
) [duplicate 3]
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 63.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 63
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 63 (collect at <stdin>:1) failed in 0.114 s
17/07/07 13:51:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 55 failed: collect at <stdin>:1, took 0.120849 s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 771, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 63.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 63.0 (TID 745, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1272, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: lower

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1272, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: lower

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concu

rrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: What exception are you getting? What is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in functions available for DataFrames, instead of converting it to RDD:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row("John"), Row("Mary")], ["name"])

lower_df = df.withColumn("name", lower(col("name")))
```

Then, to apply regex, you can use `regexp_replace(str, pattern, replacement)`:

```py
result = lower_df.withColumn("new_col", regexp_replace("name", "o", "\*"))

result.show()

+----+-------+
|name|new_col|
+----+-------+
|john|   j*hn|
|mary|   mary|
+----+-------+
```

More info about the available functions can be found in the [pyspark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions).

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'lower' is not defined

Comment: I am using Spark 1.6

Comment: @JackDaniel Have you imported `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`?